# Crash in the simulator when i try to go to an other view

Tags: iphone, view, crash, tabbar, switching

so I have a tab bar application where i have put a button to go to an other view.

so in the FirstView.h i have that

```
IBOutlet ContactMainViewController *contactMainViewController;
```

and that

```
-(IBAction)gotoContactMainViewController;
```

in my FirstView.m i have

```
-(IBAction)gotoContactMainViewController {

    [self presentModalViewController:contactMainViewController animated:YES];
}
```

and in my SecondView that i have created in the .h

```
-(IBAction)goBack;
```

and in the .m

```
-(IBAction)goBack {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The app run correctly but when i click on the button, a green line come over

```
[self presentModalViewController:contactMainViewController animated:YES];
```

and say `"Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"`
and this in the console:
`terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 3908 thread 0xb303]`

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of FirstView and ContactMainViewController class file? is it a UIViewController or simple UIView?
we assume that ContactMainViewController is a separate class file

in your firstView.m

```
#import "ContactMainViewController.h"

-(IBAction)gotoContactMainViewController {

    ContactMainViewController _contactMainVC = [[ContactMainViewController alloc]init];

    [self presentModalViewController:_contactMainVC animated:YES];
    [_contactMainVC release];
}
```

> Add the @class ContactMainViewController; in the header before the @interface. That should do it. Also be sure to #import "ContactMainViewController.h" in your .m file to avoid warnings

Comment: Good AlexF :), but problem was not much clear, but i predict it and try to give you the answer. i am just gonna improve my answer little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the code provided by Legolas just before:

```
[self presentModalViewController:contactMainViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate `contactMainViewController` before pushing views.

```
-(IBAction)gotoContactMainViewController {


if (self.contactMainViewController == nil)
  self.contactMainViewController = [[ContactMainViewController alloc] init];

[self presentModalViewController:contactMainViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but where i have to put that ?
I have to declare that ? Because when i add this into my FirstView.m, i have a error for contactMainViewContriller..
Thanks again :)

Comment: yes, i have done that but now i have a problem with the .contact... self.contactMainViewController
self.contactMainViewController

Comment: Property 'contactMainViewController' not found on object of type 'ContactViewController *'

Comment: isn't contactMainViewController an object of `ContactMainViewController` ? Why did you type ContactViewController ?

Comment: because ContactViewController is my "FirstView" and i want to go to my ContactMainViewController (my SecondView)

Comment: Did you add `IBOutlet ContactMainViewController *contactMainViewController;` as a property of `ContactViewController`?

Comment: yes i have add this in my ContactViewController.h
 
IBOutlet ContactMainViewController *contactMainViewController;

Comment: Lol. nevermind. do these. Add these two, and you are all set. `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ContactMainViewController *contactMainViewController; and then `synthesize it` in the `.m file`. Also import the `ContactMainViewController.h` in the `.m file`.

Comment: Ha ha. Good Luck ;) And yeah, do give me a +1 and accept my answer (tick mark near my answer) so that my answer helps some other person with the same problem :)

Comment: Legolas, do you think do we really need to have an ivar and set property for contactMainViewController untill unless we are not using in other place/class? Just create an object contactMainViewController(which he just want to push to modalviewcontroller) and release it. I still do not agree with your answer. **-1** from my side of your answer. **you should not beg for the credit**

Comment: @Control-V: Clearly you are right with the implementation. And yeah, +1 to your answer. I did not see your answer at first till you posted your comment here. lol. I agree with you your answer is right. But since he is setting it as an Outlet, it is wiser to add it as a property and dealloc it. And since he is also new to stack overflow, I prefer to write my answer in the most basic fashion.

Comment: @Legolas yeah he is also new for programming i guess, so we should always people to tell the right direction to do, instead of just correction. I agree with your answer too(**you also right**) but you were trying to help him out towards to his code and i just tried with my own way.

Comment: @Control-V: Lol. Yeah. Exactly. Each of us have our own principles for teaching / answering.